# Deleting all combinations of data from a table with a composite key in DB2 database

Tags: sql, db2

I have to delete data from DB2 tables which have composite keys. I can delete with a query like : `delete from <table> where <col_1> in (...) and <col_2> in (...)` etc..etc..

However I would like to build a query which is independent of input data (as filter) as that usually goes in hundreds of thousands of records.

How do I do that?

EDIT: I am sorry for this obfuscated question. There *will* be some kind of input, example - a date range for the load timestamp but it *certainly* will not be a list of input values to be deleted.

Comment: Please clarify - how do you know which values to delete?  Do you have a list of ordered tuples of key values or something?

Comment: You can either use range checks like you've mentioned (with the timestamp), or you can upload items into a temp table to check against (with a `WHERE EXISTS` + subselect); this can either be with individual/blocked `INSERT` statements, or some sort of load-file command (OS specific) - I've had to load several thousand entries that way for this type of work.  Other than that, we're probably going to need more information...